# python validate date format or blank

Tags: python

I am trying to valid user input.  I have more than one type of valid date and one that is just blank.  There may be an easy way to check this but I can't figure it out.

```
def check_input(i):
    valids = ['%Y-%m-%d', '%Y%M', '']
    while True:
        try:
            date = strptime(i, valids)
        except ValueError as e:
            print 'Could not parse: {}'. format(e)
        else:
            return True
```

I don't think I can pass a list to a strptime object. It returns TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'.

Here is a snippet of the script

```
def parse_arguments():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='API Statistics')
    parser.add_argument('-c', '--company', help='Company name')
    parser.add_argument('-d', '--download', help='Download file', action='store_true')
    return parser.parse_args()

def list_cmds(company):
    for num, cmd in enumerate(company._cmds):
        print '{}: {}'.format(num, cmd)

def get_cmd_dict(company):
    return dict(enumerate(company._cmds))

def run_cmd(i, cmd, **kwargs):
    return getattr(i, get_cmd_dict(i)[int(cmd)])(**kwargs)

def writer(data, file):
    with open(file, 'w') as f:
        f.write(data)

def get_func_args(f):
     ins = inspect.getargspec(f).args
     ins.remove('self')
     return ins

def check_input(i):
    valids = ['%Y-%m-%d', '%Y%M', '']
    while True:
        try:
            date = strptime(i, valids)
        except ValueError as e:
            print 'Could not parse: {}'. format(e)
        else:
            return True

def main():
    args = parse_arguments()

    if args.company == 'parklogic':
        i = PlAPI(11111, 'asdf', 'program', debug=False)
        pl_cmds = get_cmd_dict(i)


        print 'please select a command'
        print '-----------------------'

        list_cmds(PlAPI)

        user_cmd = raw_input('Number: ')
        print ''

        cmd_args = get_func_args(getattr(i, pl_cmds[int(user_cmd)]))
        users_args = {}
        format_mapper = {0: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
                         1: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
                         2: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
                         3: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
                         4: 'YYYYMM',
                         5: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
                         6: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss',
                         7: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
                         8: 'YYYY-MM-DD'}

        for arg in cmd_args:
            user_input = raw_input('Enter {} as {} or leave blank: '.format(
                                            arg, format_mapper[int(user_cmd)]))
            if check_input(user_input):
                users_args[arg] = user_input

        resp = run_cmd(i, user_cmd, **users_args)

        if args.download:
            writer(resp.read(), '{}.csv'.format(pl_cmds[int(user_cmd)]))
        else:
            print resp.read()

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def check_input(i):
    valids = ['%Y-%m-%d', '%Y%M', '']
    for valid in valids
        try:
            return strptime(i, valid)
        except ValueError as e:
            pass
    return False
```

Comment: When I try this and enter invalid date formats, not listed in my valid_list, I do not get any ValueErrors.

Comment: I forgot a s in valid, is it that ? Otherwise you should explain a little bit more.

Comment: i caught your typo, no worries :) I guess I'll need to make a while True loop in my main function so if an exception is raised in check_input it will prompt for input again.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes it makes sens, but check_input will not raise an exception, but it will return False if the date is not valid.

Comment: Is there a way then to do it without except ValueError as e?

Comment: @Ptrkcon I never really understand that comment whenever I see it. This is a solution, and the implementation is great. Why are we avoiding `except` blocks?

Comment: Just curious if there is another way if all you do with the try/except is pass upon exception.

Comment: @Ptrkcon That's all you're trying to do, though. You're telling Python "Hey, return `strptime(i)` for each of these valid formats, but if it doesn't work, don't worry about it and try the next one. Then if execution falls off the bottom of the `for` block, you know that NONE of those valid formats are the format of your input, so you can indicate that with `return False`

Comment: @Ptrkcon Yes, you could manually check each date by splitting on hyphens and testing `date[0]`, `date[1]` and `date[2]` for `%Y-%m-%d`. You could check for string length and check `i[:-3]`, `i[-2:]` to check `"%Y%M` but why would you do that? EAFP works a dream here. Don't think of `pass` as a placeholder: in this case it's exactly what you're trying to do.